# Ash - Complex Variables - Sufficient conditions for the absolute and uniform convergence of the infinite product of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, weierstrass-factorization

I am self studying Ash & Novinger's Complex Variables. The authors prove the following theorem [(see Page 4, Subsection 6.1.6)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV6.pdf):

> *Proposition.* Let $g_1 , g_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of **bounded** complex valued functions, each defined on a  set $S$. If the series
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert g_n \rvert$ converges uniformly on $S$,
> then the product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+g_n)$ converges absolutely
> and uniformly on $S$. Furthermore, if $f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}
>  (1+g_n(z)), z\in S$, then $f(z)=0$ iff $1+g_n(z)=0$ for some $n\in
>  \mathbb N$.

Is the bounded condition redundant? The proof never makes use of it, in fact, uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |g_n|$ implies the boundedness of $g_n$'s after a certain stage. Here's how it can be show:

Let $\sigma_n (x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} |g_k(z)|$. Since $\sigma_n$ converges uniformly, it is uniformly Cauchy ([see here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequence_of_Functions_is_Uniformly_Cauchy_iff_Uniformly_Convergent)). Thus, there is some $K \in \mathbb N$ such that for every $m,n \ge K$, we have that $|\sigma_{m} (x) - \sigma_{n} (x)| < 1$. The result is now immediate by choosing $m=n+1$ for each $n \ge N$.

Since the first few terms cannot affect convergence, we may in fact get rid of them. So what is the point of boundedness here?

Comment: You are right. In fact one of the first steps in the proof is to *conclude* that $|g_n(z)| <1$ for $n \ge N$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis makes the same assumption, so,  I thought I may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see why boundedness needs to be required a-priori. As you said, $\sigma_n (z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} |g_k(z)|$ converges uniformly on $S$, so that
$$
 |g_n(z)| = \sigma_n (z) - \sigma_{n-1} (z)
$$
converges uniformly to zero on $S$, and that implies uniform boundedness of $(g_n)_{n \ge N}$ for some $N$.